Finding a Ball that containing convex compact set $K$, but Excluding $x\notin K$
Let $K$ be a convex compact subset of norm space X. $x_0 \in X\setminus K$. How can we construct a ball $B$, such that:

$K \subseteq B$.
$x_0 \notin B$.


Here is a counterexample with the $\sup$ norm in the plane.
Let $c_0= (1,-1), c_1 = -c_0$, $C = \operatorname{co} \{ c_0, c_1 \}$ and $x_0 = (1,1)$. Note that $x_0 \notin C$. Suppose $C \subset B(y, r)$ for some $y, r>0$. In particular, $c_0,c_1 \in B(y,r)$ and so
$\max(|y_1-1|,|y_2+1|) < r$ and $\max(|y_1+1|,|y_2-1|) < r$. Combining shows that $\max(|y_1-1|,|y_2-1|) < r$, in particular, $x_0 \in B(y,r)$.

Thx for your answer.  This counterexample is correct.
If the condition is changed such that $K$ is a convex compact subset of complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and $x \notin K$, is it always possible to construct such a circle based on the Euclidean distance?

@abelcool yes, it is straightforward to show (with the Euclidean norm) that an open half space can be written as the union of a collection of nested balls.

(Sorry, I made an awful mistake here, the following counterexample is wrong.) I don't think there is always such an open ball, but an open neighbourhood is always here. For example, on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the closed square $\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \leq 1$ is convex and compact, the point $(1,1)$ is not in it, but every ball containing the square must contain that point.So here I prove the existence of such an open neighbourhood.
The method follows from the fact that a normed space must be a Hausdorff space.
For any $k \in K$, there exists two open balls $A_k$ and $B_k$ satisfying $k \in A_k$, $x \in B_k$ and $A_k \cap B_k = \emptyset$. Then all the $A_k$'s form an open cover of $K$, which implies $K$ can be covered with finitely many $A_{k_n}$'s. Name the union of these $A_{k_n}$'s as $N$, one can check that $x \not\in N$ because $x$ must be in the intersection of the finitely many $B_{k_n}$'s.
In general, this property holds in all Hausdorff spaces. The only thing to do is replace open balls mentioned in the proof with open neighbourhoods which can separate $k$ and $x$.
(New Added)
The question here may be helpful to solve this problem.

Thx for you response.
For the example $|x|+|y| \leq 1$ and the point (1,1). the desired ball is
$x^2+y^2=1+\epsilon$.
In fact, the center of the ball does not necessarily need to be at the origin.

I'm sorry for my awful mistake. I have added some marks to notify that my "counterexample" is wrong.

This answer is inspired by the first and the present version of @MingxinLI post. There is no mistake. The counterexample is correct. Although the norm is not explicitly specified, but it is clear from the context that the $\sup$ norm is used.
Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with norm $$(x_1,x_2)=|x_1|+|x_2|$$
The sides of every ball are segments parallel to one of the lines $y=\pm x.$ Let $K=[-1,1]\times [-1,1].$ Thus every ball containing $K$ must contains the set $$U=\{(x,y)\,:\, |x|+|y|\le \sqrt{2}\}$$ Hence every point in $U$ cannot be separated from $K$ by an open ball containing $K.$

It is not clear from the context that the sup norm is used in the post of @MingxinLI , although using that norm would surely make the counterexample work. It is likely, also looking at the edited answer, that they meant to equip $\mathbb R^2$ with the Eucledian norm.

@LorenzoPompili The choice of the point $(1,1)$ suggests that the sup norm is used. Make a graph of $K$ and mark the point $(1,1).$ If it is not convincing you, mark the points $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$ and draw the square formed by these points.Every ball in sup norm containing $K$ must contain the square. Take a look at the other answer: it is a copy of the example provided by MingxinLI

I get that the sup norm works, but since the user did not specify the norm (which, by the way, in many cases would actually suggest that the Eucledian norm is used), and since they also edited their answer to say that their example is wrong (why would they do it if they were using the sup norm?), it is evident that they did not mean to use the sup norm. At the very least, it is not that likely. “it is clear from the context […] is used” means that the author clearly meant to say that. I would rather say “The example works with this assumption…”, or “If the user meant $X$, then $Y$”.

I agree that the choice of the point alone would hint to the use of the sup norm, although the edited answer rules this option out (the OP even mentioned the Eucledian norm in their comment, without the answerer replying that they were using a different norm). You might disagree, which I would find fair. I say all of this because I think avoiding to attribute claims to other users when such claims are dubious or unclear generally helps to keep the whole post readable and avoids confusion in other readers

Yes,  @copper.hat has already provided the same counterexample, using the supremum norm.
